# How can I make a textbox function in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I'm looking to make about 10 textboxes for the user to type into then store that value as a variable. Is there anyway to make a textbox function with the parameters being the position?

Comment: What sort of textboxes, awt, Swing, web, Android, got any attempted code for us?

Comment: If you have no need to use processing.js you may look at GUI libraries from [contributed libraries page](http://processing.org/reference/libraries).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that’s possible using the library [controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/).

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

String[] textfieldNames = {"tf1", "tf2", "tf3", "tf4", "tf5"};

void setup() {
  size(700,400);

  PFont font = createFont("arial",20);

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  int y = 20;
  int spacing = 60;
  for(String name: textfieldNames){
    cp5.addTextfield(name)
       .setPosition(20,y)
       .setSize(100,40)
       .setFont(font)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(255,0,0))
       ;
     y += spacing;
  }

  textFont(font);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
}

void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
  if(theEvent.isAssignableFrom(Textfield.class)) {
    println("controlEvent: accessing a string from controller '"
            +theEvent.getName()+"': "
            +theEvent.getStringValue()
            );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're a proficient Java programmer, you may consider using the **[Swing Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29)**, the primary Java GUI widget toolkit. However, you'd also find yourself messing around with the Processing core code. Don't do that.

> The main rule when using Java code [in a Processing sketch]: you cannot use most of the AWT or
>   Swing (which is built on the AWT), because it will interfere with the
>   graphics model. If you want to add scroll bars and buttons to your
>   projects, you should make them using Processing code, or embed your
>   Processing applet inside another Swing or AWT application.
>   Even if they appear to work, such sketches will usually break when you
>   try to run on other operating systems or other versions of Java. – **[Processing FAQ](http://wiki.processing.org/w/FAQ)**

If you're not a Java programmer, stick with Processing libraries or make your own text field class.

The popular **[ControlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/)** GUI library has built-in classes for **[text fields](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/examples/controllers/ControlP5textfield/ControlP5textfield.pde)** and **[text areas](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/examples/controllers/ControlP5textarea/ControlP5textarea.pde)**. As of yet, This version has been tested with processing 2.0b7 and it may not work with the latest 2.0 release.

You may also use the **[G4P](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/)** library and its **[text area](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/ex-textarea/index.html)** implementation.

If it's the first time you're using external libraries, open Processing and add contributed libraries by selecting "Add Library..." from the "Import Library..." submenu within the upper bar menu.

EDIT: I've never tried it, but **[Interfascia](http://www.superstable.net/interfascia/)** (alpha release) has a **[text field](http://www.superstable.net/interfascia/examples_textfield.htm)** class too. **[The documentation](http://www.superstable.net/interfascia/iftextfield.htm)** seems easy to read and the code easy to use.